# Bash: using function with pipe as argument for another function

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I'm trying to make function-wrapper for another functions to distinguish its in terminal

```
red_line="$(tput setaf 1)## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## $(tput sgr 0)"

function wrapper {
    echo $red_line;
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)## $(tput setab 7)$(tput setaf 0)$1 $(tput sgr 0)";
    $2;
    echo $red_line;
}

function foo {
    wrapper "custom command description" "ps axo pid,stat,pcpu,comm | tail -n 10;"
}
```

but error was occurred: `ps: illegal argument: |`

I've tried to use `$(ps ... | tail -n 10)` and backticks instead of string and then print out result in wrapper with `echo $2`, but caught another errors

Also tried `"eval $(ps ... | tail -n 10)"` and it also didn't work.

Everything works just fine w/o wrapper:

```
function pss {
    echo $red_line
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)## $(tput setab 7)$(tput setaf 0)formatted 'ps ax' command $(tput sgr 0)"

    ps axo pid,stat,pcpu,comm | tail -n $1;

    echo $red_line
}
```

[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waKa5.png)

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tnx @chepner for referring post about passing complex commands as argument.
But the actual problem was with mess with double quotes in functions arguments in `echo` and `wrapper`.

Correct code:

```
red_line="$(tput setaf 1)## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## $(tput sgr 0)"

function wrapper {
    echo $red_line;
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)## $(tput setab 7)$(tput setaf 0)$1 $(tput sgr 0)";
    echo "$2";
    echo $red_line;
}

function pss {
    res="$(ps axo pid,stat,pcpu,comm | tail -n $1)"
    wrapper "custom command description" "$res"
    # also work: 
    # wrapper "custom command description" "$(ps axo pid,stat,pcpu,comm | tail -n $1)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aiven Lebowski 's answer is correct. but if you really wanted to keep foo as-is and execute $2 in place where you put it, you only needed to do eval

```
red_line="$(tput setaf 1)## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## $(tput sgr 0)"

function wrapper {
    echo $red_line;
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)## $(tput setab 7)$(tput setaf 0)$1 $(tput sgr 0)";
    eval $2
    echo $red_line;
}

function foo {
    wrapper "custom command description" "ps axo pid,stat,pcpu,comm | tail -n 10;"
}
```

I hope this helps